# How to do repository authorization with Play framework's dependencies.yml?

Tags: playframework, dependency-management

I'm using the dependency mechanism of the play framework to download libraries (see http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/dependency). However one of our maven repositories is not public and requires a username/password in order to acquire artifacts from it. They are set up in $USER_HOME/.m2/settings.xml but Play seems to ignore this. So where can I specify login credentials that Play can use to successfully download artifacts from non-public repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play! does not use Maven to build the application, but [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy) instead (sbt will be used in Play! 2.0). However, Apache Ivy relies on Maven repositories to grab the dependencies.

So in your case, I think that you have to create a `.ivy2/ivysettings.xml` file and [define the credentials there](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/use/settings.html) to give the correct access to Play!.